# Stable OpenStack distribution for computation on 1 or 2 bare metal servers

Tags: openstack

I'm looking to deploy a new private cloud using OpenStack. **What are good deployment options for OpenStack as of today (early 2020)? [1 to 2 bare metal servers, stable, mainly for compute]**

I know little about the OpenStack ecosystem. My impression is that people who use it in production usually lean on a commercial OpenStack distribution.

So I'm looking for something like an OpenStack distribution that makes installation, upgrading, etc easy. Ideally it would have a community edition (open source and free to use), but also offer commercial support options (similar to `Proxmox` in the virtualization space or `Rancher` in the Kubernetes space). However, that's not a strict requirement (just my naive idea of it), feel free to point me to any good options that you would recommend for a new installation.

Usecase in more details (TLDR):

small scale cluster (1 to 2 servers with internal storage) for compute. Looking to replace a vmware-like system with a cloud-like system to gain a more AWS EC2-like workflow. Users should be able to declare configuration as cloudformation/heat/terraform, create VPCs/virtual networks, run VM instances and attach virtual block storage to them. It should be a stable system, but it's not a mission critical system (i.e. not everything needs to be HA). Only medium/reasonable security requirements (internal use only, not directly exposed to the Internet). Version: current stable, not bleeding edge.